# what is effective way to send media like images,.. using my android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am new in android java programming and i need to create an activity which will help a user to send media like image,video, audio,.. to another user or to the group of users so that the action of sending would be super fast like whatsapp does , but i don't know which way i can follow and what i am required to know and to have . i am using android studio 2.if there is some tutorials or source codes please share with me the link. thanks for yr highest consideration to my question.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
     EditText MyText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
     Button send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     ImageView attach =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attach);

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String txt =MyText.getText().toString();
      ...
AlertDialog alertDialog = new      AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
  ...

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Defuke efficiency in your case

Comment: I don't catch you very well @Antoniosss, what would you like to mean

Comment: Define* i meant ;)

Comment: I would like to say : effective*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Firebase https://firebase.google.com/

Use Firebase Storage and also Firebase Realtime Database

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Small sample code from above link 
Upload from a local file

You can upload local files on the device, such as photos and videos from the camera, with the putFile() method. putFile() takes a File and returns an UploadTask which you can use to manage and monitor the status of the upload.

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

Comment: some tutorials for Firebase by Google https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009